# Replacing the Alt+Middle mouse shortcut

Tags: shortcut

I want to replace the Alt+Middle mouse shortcut in the keymap, but I can't find i

Comment: Did you try searching by key-binding? I can find it that way

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that, but can you tell me how it's called (alt+ middle mouse to switch to ortho view)? I still can't find it, or is it one of the "tweak" options?

Comment: If I simply press alt + middle mouse nothing happens. Only when I swipe with the mouse. Then the view aligning to the the axes and switch to ortho mode anyway. These are the tweak functions. You can swap between ortho and persp mode with numpad 5.